# LWJGL How can I render texture shape in white color

Tags: opengl, blending

I want to render texture shape in plain white.
What I mean by that is that I want to render rabbit shape but compleatly black. I have colored texture of rabbit and I wanna use it to render it all white. I want to keep alpha transparent.

I can render it with black by using:

```
glBlendFunc(GL_ZERO, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

but how can I do it to achive white?

Here's my rabbit:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wrobelp/GameEngine/master/res/rabbit.png

Works like this:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_ADD);
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

// Draw textured quad.

// Back to normal
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
```

Comment: go in your fragment shader and change it to just `gl_FragColor=vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);`

Comment: I don't use fragment shader. Can I do is somehow by blending?

Comment: Not with blending alone, unfortunately. But this can be done with texture combiners. If you have a texture that is pure white and a texture that has an alpha channel as your mask, you can replace the outgoing RGB with the white texture's RGB and the outgoing alpha with the rabbit's alpha. You can't substitute a texture's alpha channel for the RGB though unfortunately - you need a shader for that sort of thing.

Comment: I wrote a potential answer, but now that I think about it, I'm not quite sure what your rabbit texture looks like. Does it have an alpha channel or is it based on color key transparency? Can you include a picture of the rabbit texture in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### This can be done using texture combiners.

The idea is to replace the color channel of your rabbit texture with white, while keeping the alpha channel the same.

#### Setup a texture combiner to combine a constant white color with your alpha mask:

```
 GLfloat white [4] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

 glBindTexture   (GL_TEXTURE_2D, rabbitTexture);
 glTexEnvi       (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_COMBINE);
 glTexEnvfv      (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_COLOR, white);

 glTexEnvi       (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_RGB,  GL_REPLACE);
 glTexEnvi       (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_RGB,  GL_CONSTANT);  // RGB   = White
 glTexEnvi       (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_RGB, GL_SRC_COLOR);

 glTexEnvi       (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_COMBINE_ALPHA,  GL_REPLACE);
 glTexEnvi       (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_SOURCE0_ALPHA,  GL_TEXTURE); // Alpha = Mask
 glTexEnvi       (GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_OPERAND0_ALPHA, GL_SRC_ALPHA);
```

This requires OpenGL 1.3 to work, but can be done without a fragment shader since you mentioned you didn't want to use one.

Comment: Thank You for Your help. I think that better idea is to prepare texture I need before. I'm trying to achive it inside program for like 3 days without any effect. I will save time, and after all program will work faster.

Comment: Yes, that is definitely the better approach to this problem. By the way, the reason the screen becomes red the way you did it is because you only set one of the color channels to **1.0f** with this call: `glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_COLOR, 1f)` - you need to use `glTexEnvfv` to set all 4 color channels.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using `GL_ADD` for the texture env mode:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texId);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_ADD);
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);

// Draw textured quad.
```

Using `GL_ADD` for the env mode means that the texture color and the fragment color are added for the RGB components. By setting the fragment color to white with the `glColor4f()` call, the sum of the two will always be white.

For the alpha component in `GL_ADD` mode, the texture alpha and fragment alpha are **multiplied**. Which is somewhat surprising, but this is the way it is specified. Since the code above sets the fragment alpha to `1.0f`, the result of the multiplication will be the texture alpha value.

Then, by using the common `(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` as the blend function, the opaque parts of the texture will be drawn with the resulting color of the texture env calculation (which is white), while the previous color remains untouched for the transparent parts of the texture.

Comment: how to use GL_ADD? When should I render, and should I enable/disable anything?

Comment: The code I posted contains all the settings you need. Except for creating a texture and filling it with data, of course. You draw after setting up the state (I added a comment for that). I actually tried this, and copied it from the working code, so this is complete and tested.